# google-signin signs in, but not out

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to build an app using Polymer 1.0. I want to use the standard google-signin widget to log the user in to Google. That works fine --- it's really easy.

Trouble is, pressing the button again is supposed to log the user out. This isn't working. It just doesn't do anything. I can trace the click handler, and follow code down into the obfuscated low-level stuff, but nothing happens. There's not even any network traffic.

The weird thing is that:

(a) their demo works;

(b) when I cut-and-paste the demo code into my own app, it still doesn't work.

I've gotten nowhere comparing the behaviour of their demo ([the one here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-signin?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=google-signin) and my app, because whatever's happening happens deep inside the obfuscated auth layer somewhere.

Any suggestions? Is it possible that I somehow created a client ID which doesn't allow logging out (although that seems really weird)?

Comment: Are you testing this on localhost or deployed on a webserver? Because of this sign-out functionality depending on Google-cookies it won't work properly on localhost.

Comment: Blechh. Yes, I was using localhost. I did try using raw `gapi.auth2`, which exhibited the same problem, but also gave me login tokens that wouldn't actually work --- attempting to use them gave me errors asking for token refresh. Is this a symptom of the same issue? Meanwhile I am now using `gapi.auth`, which works fine from localhost.

Comment: In addition, I have totally failed to find any mention of this in the docs. Plenty of confused people asking about why it's not working, though!